# Promotional Email to Sales Cloud contacts using Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, automationstudio

I want to create an automation which will send email to all the contacts from sales cloud.

So it will be a promotional holiday email like (Fathers day , New year ,Good friday etc).

I already connect marketing cloud and sales cloud.

Can any one suggest the best approach to start with automation studio  like which activity will be use full?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, please take some time to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the tour. Step-by-step instruction isn't really Stack Exchange's model. So you need to try it yourself and once you have done so, make sure you include details of your problem (screenshots, steps to reproduce etc.) alongside with any errors you get when applied your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SFSE!

For your request to send Emails to Contacts from Sales Cloud, first you will need to have the [Marketing Cloud Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_marketing_cloud_connect.htm&type=5) fully configured between the two Clouds.

This will enable cross-cloud features such as using Sales Cloud contacts in Automations and Journeys and updating or creating Sales Cloud records real-time from Marketing Cloud, plus many other things.

Assuming you have the Marketing Cloud Connect in place and Contacts are synchronising from Sales Cloud to Marketing Cloud, you'll need to prepare the [Data Extensions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_data_extensions.htm&type=5) in Email Studio to hold your audiences for these specific sends.

In your Data Extensions you will need to define some mandatory fields like `Email` (with also set as the EmailAddress type) and `SubscriberKey` (which in your case will be the long, 18-digit ContactID from Sales Cloud).

Once you have your Data Extensions set up, you can create [SQL Query Activities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5) in Automation Studio to write up a query that matches your criteria. 
For an example, finding all Person Accounts that have an Email address and have given you the consent to contact them.

The results of this SQL Query Activity will then be stored to the previously created Data Extension.

Second option is to use [Data Filter](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_data_filter_definition.htm&type=5) Activity, which is more of a drag and drop segmentation tool and is fine for easier audiences as you have described.

Finally in your Automation you will need to select the Email you are going to be using, define any dynamic content on it and set the Automation schedule.

To learn more how to start with Marketing Cloud, here are some resources:

- [Salesforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules) (check for Marketing Cloud modules)
- [Official Marketing CloudDocumentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_welcome.htm&type=5)
- [Marketing Cloud Success Community](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001pQ5)